# Animate list and list of lists with animated matplotlib in the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

I am trying to animate a list and a list of lists in the same plot where the value of list should appear in one color and the list of lists in another color. My entry for list works fine but however, I am unable to see the list of lists data getting plotted in the same plot with green color.

```
def update_lines(num, data1, data2, line1, line2):
    line1.set_data(data1[..., :num])
    line2.set_data(data2[0][num],data2[1][num])
    return line1, line2


list_x = []
list_y = []
listoflist_x = []
listoflist_y = []


data1 = np.array([list_x,list_y])
data2 = np.array([listoflist_x,listoflist_y])


fig1 = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(121)

l1, = ax1.plot([], [], 'r-')
ax1.set_xlim(-127,50)
ax1.set_ylim(-235,21)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l2, = ax2.plot([], [],'go',markersize=1)

line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_lines, frames=1000, fargs=(data1,data2,l1,l2),interval=1, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset and expected result? It's hard to tell how `data1` and `data2` are different and how they should be plotted.

Comment: they both contain set floating point numbers (x in the range of -400 to 200) and y (-500 to 100). The list of lists appear as green circles and the x,y points for the list appear as red dash. so for each frame there will be one red dash and multiple green points

Comment: Did you check the limits of the twin axes? Would you expect the data inside those limits?

Comment: yes...thats the first thing I checked. I set the limit to the max and min value of both the data

Comment: Could it be a simple typo? In your `update_lines` function, you get `line2` and `line3` as input, but you return `line1` and `line2`.

Comment: @ThomasKühn: hey its not that error. I have modified the question. I had fixed that on my side earlier

Comment: Well, I guess we can't really help you without some example input data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You have set the limits of `ax1`, but not the limits of `ax2`. Also in the commets you report about ranges of the order of -500..200, but in the code you have -200..50.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: yes you got it right. setting the limits of ax2 solved the issue and made it work. Thanks. you can post it as an answer